# NullPointerException when trying to use ressource in Eclipse

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am making a runnable jar file for my project.

**Code**

```
public class StandingsCreationHelper
{
    private static final String TEMPLATE_FILENAME = "Standings_Template.xls";

public static void createStandingsFile() throws Exception
{
    StandingsCreationHelper sch = new StandingsCreationHelper();

    // Get the file from the resources folder
    File templateFile = new File("TemporaryPlaceHolderExcelFile.xls");
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(templateFile);
    IOUtils.copy(sch.getFile(TEMPLATE_FILENAME), outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
}
}

public InputStream getFile(String fileName)
{
    return this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    createStandingsFile();
}
```

**Project's structure**

[image]

**Question**

When I package my code in the runnable jar, my program will execute without any problems. However, if I call the main method from my IDE (Eclipse), I get the following error message, as if the resource cannot be found:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:182)
    at standings.StandingsCreationHelper.createStandingsFile(StandingsCreationHelper.java:153)
    at standings.StandingsCreationHelper.main(StandingsCreationHelper.java:222)

Thanks for advance for any help!

Comment: `"/resources/Standings_Template.xls";` ???

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Changing to the mentioned string still returns a null pointer exception.

Comment: what is null, the input or the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `getClassLoader()` which needs the absolute Path to the File.

Change:

```
public InputStream getFile(String fileName)
{
    return this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}
```

to

```
public InputStream getFile(String fileName)
{
    return this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}
```

Now your can use the relative path, seen from your class. Don't forget to change `TEMPLATE_FILENAME` to `"resources/Standings_Template.xls"` as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, the changes still lead to a NullPointerException.

Comment: Maybe try without the leading slash TEMPLATE_FILENAME = "resources/Standings_Template.xls"